# becomeFirstResponder failed

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a simple question:

How to set up the code to have a NSObject becoming the first responder? In my code, I put this code into AppDelegate but the app delegate failed to become the first responder. Same happen to me if I tried to let another NSObject to become the firstResponder.

```
//This function is called when app enters background
- (void)prepareRemoteControlEventsListener{

    //register for remote control
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];

    // Set itself as the first responder
    BOOL success = [self becomeFirstResponder];
    if (success) {
        NSLog(@"APP degelgate AVManager for remote control events");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"@@@ degelgate failed to listen remote control events @@@");
    }
}
//Suppose it should enable self becoming firstResponder?
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: what are you going to achieve by making appdelegate as first responder?

Comment: it might be too early to call this in app delegate , because a view my not be in hierarchy yet

Comment: Your appdelegate is a subclass of `UIResponder` ?

Comment: Emmanuel, AppDelegate is a UIResponder for every app, isn't it?

Comment: rajesh, I am trying to receive remote control event by calling beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents

Comment: meda, I called this method when app goes to background, when all views displayed properly.